# How to download entire directory from azure file share

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-files

Not able to download entire directory from azure file share in python

I have  used all basic stuffs available in google

```
share = ShareClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, "filshare")
my_file = share.get_file_client("dir1/sub_idr1")
# print(dir(my_file))
stream_1 = my_file.download_file()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @shreedhar hegde Have you tried a any piece of code to download the directory?

Comment: yes i did tried this one.from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareFileClient

file_client = ShareFileClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="<connection_string>", share_name="my_share", file_path="my_file")

with open("DEST_FILE", "wb") as file_handle:
    data = file_client.download_file()
    data.readinto(file_handle)

Comment: Can you include the code you have used by editing the thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I tried with python,

- Unfortunately, **`ShareServiceClient`** Class which Interacts with A client to interact with the File Share Service at the account level. does not yet support Download operation in the **[Azure Python SDK.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.shareserviceclient?view=azure-python)**
- **`ShareClient`** Class which only interacts with specific file Share in the account does not support Download Directory or file share option **[Python SDK.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.shareclient?view=azure-python)**.
- But there's one class **`ShareFileClient`** Class which supports downloading of individual files inside a directory but not entire directory, you can use this class to download the files from directory with **[Python SDK.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.sharefileclient?view=azure-python)**

Also you check ***Azure Portal > Select your Storage account > File Share and Directory > There's no option in Portal too to download the directory, but there's an option to download specific file.***

As workaround, if you need to download directory from file-share, you can use **[Az copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files#download-a-directory)** tool command to download the directory in your local machine.

I tried to download the Directory with **`Az-copy`** command and was able to download to it successfully!

**Command:**

```
azcopy copy 'https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/myFileShareDirectory?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bjqt&srs=sco&sp=rjklhjup&se=2019-05-10T04:37:48Z&st=2019-05-09T20:37:48Z&spr=https&sig=/SOVEFfsKDqRry4bk3xxxxxxxx' 'C:\myDirectory' --recursive --preserve-smb-permissions=true --preserve-smb-info=true
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Local environment:**
[image]